# Authenticate Motion video stream via Apache web server on my PI

Tags: motion, apache-httpd

At the moment I'm running two PIs with the popular software Motion, delivering webcam content to the internet.

I'm port mapping the two external ports to the internal ports on my router, to give external access to the two streams.

These two PIs have a version of Motion that allows authentication of the streams within the Motion software.

However, I have recently setup another PI with the the latest version of Motion, but without the ability to authenticate the stream. I know there's a patch for this, but was wondering:

1) Is it's possible to authenticate the three PIs, via my own Apache web server on one of the PIs; rather than from within Motion's settings?

2) If this is possible,then would I only have to port map my router to one port, the one with the web server on it?

3) Would I just use the same internal addresses link (102.168.1.90:port_number_setup_in_motion), to access the stream on the external address website?

I think [this below](http://sourceforge.net/p/motion/mailman/message/30130427/) may be close to what I'm looking for, but not sure where to place it in the appachie2 file structure.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName http://www.example.com 
     ServerAlias example.com
     DocumentRoot /opt/http-root/
     <IfModule itk.c>
         AssignUserID apache apache
     </IfModule>

     <Location /motion> #ww.example.com/motion
       AuthType Basic
       AuthUserFile /opt/not-http-root/passwords/motion.htpassword
       AuthName "Protected Motion"
       Require valid-user
     </Location>

     <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
     </Proxy>

     ProxyPass /motion http://127.0.0.1:8081
     ProxyPassReverse /motion http://127.0.0.1:8081

</VirtualHost>
```